# Fancy box not working in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i have a fancy box on my web page and also a jquery menu bar. Iam woking in the chrome its working fine but its not working in ie., I have tried by adding the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

But its not working for me. Please help me

version ie8 and 
my menubar js is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(function() {
                $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
                animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-5', classout : 'dl-animate-out-5' }
            });
        });


        </script>
```

For fancy box

```
 <!-- Fancy Box-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
                $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            });
         </script>
<!-- Fancy Box-->
```

Comment: You should seriously provide some more information , your jQuery code, browser version , etc etc , providing the html tag does not help to provide an support

Comment: i have edited my code @Arsh

Comment: You mean they are not working together (fancybox and menubar) but working individually?

Comment: No both are not working in IE

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you're using this version of jQuery because it's most compatible with IE7:

[jQuery 1.11.3](http://jquery.com/download/)

See, jQuery 2.x is made for IE9+ only:

http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Also, I recommend switching to Colorbox because it says it supports IE7+:

https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox